# Tx_News_ViewHelpers Generate Link to another site in same typo3

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

I would like to create a link to a news-detail-page, but this news-detail-page is on another URL (both pages are in the same typo3-installation).

So for example I list news-article on www.domain**1**.com, the link to the detailpage shall be www.domain**2**.com/article/123 (article/123 is just how RealURL build the link).

Right now the link is generated with this code in News/Partials/List/Item.html

```
{n:link(newsItem: newsItem, settings: settings, uriOnly: 1)}
```

but this generates a link to: www.domain**1**.com/article/123.

Best would be if the news viewhelper automaticly determinates where the news-article is coming from (where the news-container is), but it would be also very good if I just could manually say what URL it shall take.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but maybe using `{n:link(newsItem: newsItem, settings: settings, uriOnly: 1, configuration: '{forceAbsoluteUrl: 1}')}` works? The `configuration`-parameter takes a typolink-configuration.

Comment: @josh I tried different things (this too), I think there is no way cause the baseurl is set to domain**1**. I also think I am lucky that the realURL config and the sitestructure is the same for both site. So my workaround is to use a regex to replace domain**1** with domain**2** in the link.

Comment: Maybe try to unset `baseUrl` and use `absRefPrefix = /`instead, and then use domain records for defining the domains (should be there already). These settings could be relevant too: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#setup-config-typolinkcheckrootline

Comment: @Jost good point. And then I could use a normal typolink with tx_news params. Something like `<v:link.typolink configuration="{parameter: page.uid, additionalParams: '&tx_news_pi1[news]={news_uid}' ">`. I will test it